# How to write a MySQL event script

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

How can I create a MySQL event that can be run every 10 minutes and update the table based on `TIMESTAMP` column? I have a table like:

[image]

Now I need to have a My SQL event which can loop to the table and update all `pending` from `1` to `0` **IF/WHERE** `Date` is 10 minutes older than `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on event time.

```
CREATE EVENT test_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
DO
UPDATE `pending` SET = 0 WHERE `Date` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of a cronjob you can achieve this easily. Just create a script on backend which would run the script.

What is cronjob?

you can read more about the cronjobs works: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-in-ubuntu/